# module user doesn't accept encrypt password generated by ansible-vault?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

Recently I used 'user' module to create user with password provided in vars/main.yml

```
- name: Create pamuser
  user:
    name: pamuser
    password: "{{ pamuser_pass }}"
    groups: wheel
    append: yes
  tags: pamuser
```

Once run a playbook, it gives me this warning

```
TASK [prerequisite : Create pamuser] *****************************************************************************
[WARNING]: The input password appears not to have been hashed. The 'password' argument must be encrypted for this
module to work properly.
```

Then I use ansible-vault encrypt_string command to encrypt only the specific variable `"pamuser_pass"`by replace plaintext with vault password that ansible-vault gave me

contents in /vars/main.yml

```
---
# vars file for prerequisite role
pamuser_pass: !vault |
              $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
              65643265346231613137396339303834396663383466636631646337303235306137386534396266
              3364333534616238396465626436376561323762303139620a376630643131323133336164373237
              64663332363233303032636638306566303034393137636533373332383334333439663930613232
              3737
```

then I remove current pamuser and re-run the playbook with command

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --tags "pamuser" --ask-pass -K --ask-vault-pass
```

Along with the running process, it still shows the warning

```
[WARNING]: The input password appears not to have been hashed. The 'password' argument must be encrypted for this
    module to work properly.
```

the outcome seem fine with id pamuser but once logging in with ssh pamuser@example.com then put the regular password, the password doesn't work. I can't login with that pamuser.

Is there something that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be following one of the recommended ways mentioned 
[here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-encrypted-passwords-for-the-user-module) to provide the hash. It's not the general vault encryption in ansible. This is specific to the user module. Below is from the doc:

> How do I generate encrypted passwords for the user module? Ansible
>   ad-hoc command is the easiest option:

```
    ansible all -i localhost, -m debug -a "msg={{ 'mypassword' | password_hash('sha512',
  'mysecretsalt') }}"
```

> The mkpasswd utility that is available on most
>   Linux systems is also a great option:

```
mkpasswd --method=sha-512
```

Comment: yes! it works. That my bad for not looking at official article in the first place. One more question, only the password in user module that  required a special way? Can we use ansible-vault with other module?

Comment: Yes, ansible vault works with other modules but always refer official doc of the modules for more info!

Comment: If the answer helped please accept it as an answer! @banthita